# Without using a loop, check numerous conditions in a column using pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a huge dataset (rows more than 10 million), like:

```
az
az
az
az
ca
bb
bb
bb
az
ca
bb
.
.
.
```

There are a few constraints, such as the fact that "ca" cannot come after "az" and "az" cannot come after "bb". Is there a quick method to accomplish this using Pyspark without using a loop.

I would like to include a column that like the one below.

```
"ca" cannot come after "az" ---- replace "ca" with "az"
"az" cannot come after "bb" ---- replace "az" with "bb"

    az
    az
    az
    az
    az
    bb
    bb
    bb
    ca
    ca
    ca
     .
     .
```

Comment: You, can use orderby function to sort

Comment: Please provide a more detailed description of the results you want,eg:just delete 'ca' after 'az'.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by `Luff Li` you appear to be requesting functionality of `order by`. You can place multiple conditions such as:

```sql
order by col1 desc, 
         some_function(col2), 
         col3 desc
```

In this case the sql analyzer within `spark` will be able to "consider" all of the sorting conditions at one time avoiding the "for loop" you mentioned.